# Make a sequence of 2 requests with Combine in Swift?

Tags: swift, sequence, future, combine, publisher

I have the following code:

```swift
import Combine

func login() -> Future<Token, Error> { ... }
func updateImage() -> Future<Status, Never> { ... }

login()
    .flatMap { response -> Future<Status, Error> in
        // handle response and save token locally
        return updateImage()
    }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { error in
        ... //handleError
    }, receiveValue: { response in
        ... // handle response and a different error
    })
    .store(in: ...)
```

I want to join `login()` and `updateImage()` into a sequence. However, I found that `zip` is only for parallel requests. I need a way to chain them sequentially, and I am not sure if `map`, `tryMap`, or `mapError` methods can help me achieve that. I need to not only transform but also handle the response data and errors from each function.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I created "nested" requests but Combine (and other libraries with `Futures`) usually also provide a syntax when you just call `future.someHandler(...).someHandler2(...).someHandler3(...)...` - without of nesting. Or if Combine doesn't allow that?

Comment: tried flatMap - now I get error `flatMap` is not available in iOS 13

Comment: That can't be true with the code you posted. What are you flat mapping it to? Are you trying to flatmap to a publisher that `Never` fails? That would indeed call [an overload of `flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/future/flatmap(maxpublishers:_:)-61pe1) that isn't available in iOS 13.

Comment: Yes, `flatMap` only works with same error types prior to iOS 14. Do you have different error types? If so, [edit] the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm very sorry I really use `Never` in the second call. But how to deal with it in iOS 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 14+, there is a [new overload of `flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/future/flatmap(maxpublishers:_:)-nd14) that allows you flat map to a publisher that `Never` fails, so you just need to change the explicit return type of your closure to match the type that `updateImage` returns:

```
.flatMap { response -> Future<Status, Never> in // change "Error" to "Never"
```

Prior to iOS 14, you would need to use `setFailureType(to:)`:

```
.flatMap { response -> Publishers.SetFailureType<Future<Status, Never>, Error> in
    // ...
    return updateImage().setFailureType(to: Error.self)
}
```

If you don't like such a long type name, use `AnyPublisher`:

```
.flatMap { response -> AnyPublisher<Status, Error> in
    // ...
    return updateImage().setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```